# ipywidgets SelectMultiple on multiple Dropdown menu

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, ipywidgets

I have 2 dropdown menus : 1) Num Clusters and 2) Cluster

Num Clusters is one of (1,2,3,4,5) and  Cluster depends on what is selected as Num Clusters

I want to select multiple clusters at Cluster dropdown menu. The problem is "Cluster" dropdown menu does not update with "Num Cluster" dropdown selection.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ipywidgets as widgets

dict_cls = {1:np.array([1,1,1,1,1]), 2:np.array([1,2,1,1,1]), 3:np.array([1,2,3,1,1]), 4:np.array([1,2,3,4,1]), 5:np.array([1,2,3,4,5])}

dd_numcls = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=sorted(dict_cls.keys()),
    value=min(dict_cls.keys()),
    description='Num Cluster:')

dd_cls = widgets.SelectMultiple(
    options=sorted(np.unique(dict_cls[dd_numcls.value])),
    value=(min(sorted(np.unique(dict_cls[dd_numcls.value]))),),
    description='Cluster:')

b_update_cls = widgets.Button(
    description='Select Cluster')

def change_numcls(b):
    tmp_lst = np.unique(dict_cls[dd_numcls.value])
    dd_cls.options = sorted(tmp_lst)
    dd_cls.value = min(tmp_lst)

dd_numcls.observe(change_numcls)

output_filter = widgets.VBox(
    [ widgets.HBox([dd_numcls, dd_cls, b_update_cls]), ] ,
    layout=widgets.Layout(width='2100px'))

output_filter
```

[image: SelectMultiple : Cluster dropdown menu does not update.]

However, If i use Dropdown instead of SelectMultiple, then "cluster" updates without problem:

```
dd_cls = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=sorted(np.unique(dict_cls[dd_numcls.value])),
    value=(min(sorted(np.unique(dict_cls[dd_numcls.value]))),),
    description='Cluster:')
```

[image: Dropdown]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can show the error message you received (rather that 'it didn't work'), that's normally helpful.

The error message is quite instructive here.

```
TraitError: The 'value' trait of a SelectMultiple instance expected a tuple, not the int64 1.
```

If you change your assignments to `dd_cls.value` from integers to tuples, I think that's the behaviour you want.

```py
import numpy as np
import ipywidgets as widgets

dict_cls = {1:np.array([1,1,1,1,1]), 2:np.array([1,2,1,1,1]), 3:np.array([1,2,3,1,1]), 4:np.array([1,2,3,4,1]), 5:np.array([1,2,3,4,5])}

dd_numcls = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=sorted(dict_cls.keys()),
    value=min(dict_cls.keys()),
    description='Num Cluster:')

dd_cls = widgets.SelectMultiple(
    options=sorted(np.unique(dict_cls[dd_numcls.value])),
    value=(min(sorted(np.unique(dict_cls[dd_numcls.value]))),),     # now a tuple
    description='Cluster:')

b_update_cls = widgets.Button(
    description='Select Cluster')

def change_numcls(b):
    tmp_lst = np.unique(dict_cls[dd_numcls.value])
    dd_cls.options = sorted(tmp_lst)
    dd_cls.value = (min(tmp_lst),)  # now a tuple

dd_numcls.observe(change_numcls)

output_filter = widgets.VBox(
    [ widgets.HBox([dd_numcls, dd_cls, b_update_cls]), ] ,
    layout=widgets.Layout(width='2100px'))

output_filter
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I don't get an error. My problem is that "Cluster" dropdown menu does not update with "Num Cluster" dropdown selection. Please check the attached screenshots in my answer.

Comment: I updated the code like you proposed to have tuple. I added more snapshots in the question. Could you please check them?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "value" and "dd_cls_value" were not tuples. Below code works perfectly fine. Thanks to @ac24

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ipywidgets as widgets

dict_cls = {1:np.array([1,1,1,1,1]), 2:np.array([1,2,1,1,1]), 3:np.array([1,2,3,1,1]), 4:np.array([1,2,3,4,1]), 5:np.array([1,2,3,4,5])}

dd_numcls = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=sorted(dict_cls.keys()),
    value=min(dict_cls.keys()),
    description='Num Cluster:')

dd_cls = widgets.SelectMultiple(
    options=sorted(np.unique(dict_cls[dd_numcls.value])),
    value=(min(sorted(np.unique(dict_cls[dd_numcls.value]))),),   #TUPLE
    description='Cluster:')

b_update_cls = widgets.Button(
    description='Select Cluster')

def change_numcls(b):
    tmp_lst = np.unique(dict_cls[dd_numcls.value])
    dd_cls.options = sorted(tmp_lst)
    dd_cls.value = (min(tmp_lst),)    #TUPLE

dd_numcls.observe(change_numcls)

output_filter = widgets.VBox(
    [ widgets.HBox([dd_numcls, dd_cls, b_update_cls]), ] ,
    layout=widgets.Layout(width='2100px'))

output_filter
```